# How to make dynamically changing drop-down menu's in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, scripting, netsuite

Suppose there are two drop down menu's in a page and I want to change the second drop-down menu based on the selection of the first one.

#### For Example.

The first drop-down menu has a list of record types. If I select the `customer` record type, the second drop-down menu should automatically change to a list of customers. Same with `script deployments` etc.

Not only the drop down menu's but also any dynamic action in a suitelet page.

#### What I've tried

I've created a suitelet with a drop-down menu. When the form is submitted the script takes the value and populates the menu.

```
var start = function(request, response) {
    if(request.getMethod() == 'GET') {
        var form1 = nlapiCreateForm('New Form 1');
        var select1 = form1.addField('custpage_select1', 'select', 'Select A record Type', '-123');
        form1.addSubmitButton('submit');
        response.writePage(form1);
    }
    else {
        var id = request.getParameter('custpage_select1');
        var form2 = nlapiCreateForm('New Form 2');
        var select2 = form2.addField('custpage_select2', 'select', 'Select A record Value', id);
        response.writePage(form2);
    }
}
```

What I need is this whole thing in a single form. Something like,

```
var start = function(request, response)  {
    var form1 = nlapiCreateForm('New Form 1');
    var select1 = form1.addField('custpage_select1', 'select', 'Select A record Type', '-123');
    var select2 = form1.addField('custpage_select2', 'select', 'Select A record Type', XXXXX);//the source of the 1st select field
    form1.addSubmitButton('submit');
    response.writePage(form1);
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Could you please provide some code snippet to have a better clarity.

Comment: You can use `var select2 = form1.addField('custpage_select2', 'select', 'Select A record Type', form1.getField('custpage_select1');` if you want to replace `XXXXX` with the previous selected value

Comment: That doesn't work as getField() returns a nlobjField, but the addField()'s source expects an internal id.

Comment: Sorry I see your point. You're right  `getField()` will return you only the reference not the internal id. For getting the internal id you've to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Thank you @humble.rumble. I'm new to StackOverflow. So I didn't know the formatting tactics.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code

```js
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
        var Customer = new Array('Customer1', 'Customer2', 'Customer3');
        var Script = new Array('Script1', 'Script2', 'Script3');
        var etc = new Array('etc1', 'etc2', 'etc3');
    
        switch (ddl1.value) {
            case 'Customer':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < Customer.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, Customer[i], Customer[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'Script':
                ddl2.options.length = 0; 
            for (i = 0; i < Script.length; i++) {
                createOption(ddl2, Script[i], Script[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'etc':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < etc.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, etc[i], etc[i]);
                }
                break;
                default:
                    ddl2.options.length = 0;
                break;
        }

    }

    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        ddl.options.add(opt);
    }
```

```html
<select id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Customer">Customer</option>
<option value="Script">Script</option>
<option value="etc">etc</option>
</select>

<select id="ddl2">
</select>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @BhandariS for the code, but I needed the code for NetSuite which uses a separate script called SuiteScript. This code won't work there.